# Prevent AngularJs from loading hidden directives

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive based on jQuery UI datepicker :

```
myApp.directive('uiDatepicker', function ($http, $compile, $parse, InitializationService, Shared, PeriodService)
    {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        transclude: false,
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            //...
            return function ($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                //...
                element.datepicker({
                    inline: true,
                    showOtherMonths: false,
                    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
                    onSelect: processChange, //above function
                    beforeShowDay: renderDay
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Until a user clicks a button this element is hidden (using **ng-show**), once the the button is clicked the calendar should appear.

The problem is that even when it's hidden Angular still tries to load it and calls a function specified under **compile:** section.

Since the data necessary for the calendar initialization is not available until the button is clicked I receive **Cannot read property '...' of undefined**

Is there a way to tell Angular to load a directive only if it's not hidden?

Comment: instead of doing that, can you not add the directive into DOM until the button is clicked? .i.e. once the button is clicked, you create the directive and insert it into correct place?

Comment: Could you please share the HTML of the directive.

Comment: Tried using ng-if instead of ng-show ? that way it won't load if you don't want to  ...

Comment: Thanks, @Cétia, good point, I can do it this way!